# Migration several components Sandbox to Production

Tags: force.com, sandbox, migration-tool, migration

I have to migrate a ton of changes from sandbox to production. These include -
- New profiles
- New record types
- New Custom Fields
- New Custom Settings
- FLS
- New Page Layouts
- Workflows
- Translations etc.

What would be the best way to do this migration?
What order should I follow to ensure nothing gets missed out?
Please advise? Is there any best practice documentation?
Thanks!

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000171224&language=en_US
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool

Comment: haven't tried it myself, but probably that would help - http://www.kellpartners.com/kell-labs/93-how-to-move-your-configuration-from-a-salesforce-com-sandbox-to-production-using-change-sets